# To get the file extension of the files present in each row using shell script

Tags: shell, file

How to get the file extension of the below shown data. Apparently, I have millions of rows in the csv file.

```
col1                             ,col2     ,col3                        ,col4     , col5, col6, col7
aaaaa/                           ,0        ,2018-03-16T09:31:42.000Z,   xx-daily.......
aaaaa/201802/                    ,0        ,2019-01-17T06:16:34.000Z,   xx-daily
aaaaa/201802/Feb2018000000_0.gzip,32602738,2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z,    xx-daily
aaaaa/201802/Feb2018000001_0.gzip,32602738,2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z,    xx-daily
aaaaa/201802/Feb2018000002_0.gzip,32602738,2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z,    xx-daily
aaaaa/201802/Feb2018000003_0.gzip,32602187,2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z,    xx-daily
aaaaa/201802/Feb2018000004_0.gzip,32602187,2018-09-11T04:05:39.000Z,    xx-daily
aaaaa/201802/Feb2018000005_0.gzip,32602187,2018-09-11T04:05:39.000Z,    xx-daily
aaaaa/201802/Feb2018000006_0.gzip,32578449,2018-09-11T04:05:39.000Z,    xx-daily
```

I need to split the file extension and create another column to populate the file extension value in the same csv file.

Need the output as below

```
col1                             ,col2     ,col3                        ,col4     , col5, col6, col7
aaaaa/                                      ,0         ,2018-03-16T09:31:42.000Z,   xx-daily.......
aaaaa/201802/                               ,0         ,2019-01-17T06:16:34.000Z,   xx-daily
aaaaa/201802/Feb2018000000_0.gzip, gzip     ,32602738,2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z, xx-daily
aaaaa/201802/Feb2018000001_0.gzip, gzip     ,32602738,2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z, xx-daily
aaaaa/201802/Feb2018000002_0.gzip, gzip     ,32602738,2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z, xx-daily
```

Comment: Your sample output doesn't look right.  The line with `aaaaa/` in the first column in your output has fewer columns, so your output isn't really a csv anymore.  You'll need a place holder for rows without any "extension" (by which I assume you mean "string following the final `.`")

Comment: The csv contains both folder name and file name with extension. so i need to get the extension value alone for those values which has the filename with extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit clunky, does not add the spaces that you seem to want, and introduces a blank column in those rows that do not have a file extension (I believe that is correct behavior, and it's easy enough to modify this to stop doing that if you like).  However, under no circumstances would I condone writing back into the same file from which you are reading.  Some implementations of awk provide a feature for doing so, but using it is misguided.  Use a filter and write your output to a different file. If you need to, you can overwrite the original file.

```
awk '{c=split($1,a,"."); ext=c>1?a[c]:""; $2=ext OFS $2}1' FS=, OFS=, input-file
```

You can get better spacing with:

```
awk '{c=split($1,a,"."); ext=c>1?a[c]:""; $2=ext OFS $2}1' FS=, OFS=',\t' input
```

and you can avoid the empty column (but you really don't want to do this) with:

```
awk '{c=split($1,a,"."); if( c > 1) $2=a[c] OFS $2}1' FS=, OFS=',\t' input
```

Comment: I have scenario where the files saved are with 2 extension as shown below

part-00000-ad68be9228df.csv.lz4 

how can we handle this to get the lz4 only.